# store cookie in figma desktop using nodejs api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, cookies, figma

I am creating a figma plugin using typescript. I am creating a login module in the plugin. i have created the api with nodejs. the issue that i am facing is that my cookie is not getting stored.

I have opened the console for figma desktop app, but there is no cookie.

can we create the cookie with nodejs and store them in desktop app ?

```
Code for Nodejs:
```

```
app.post("/user-login", async(req,res)=>{
const {email, password} = req.body;
db.query(`select * from users where email = '${email}' and role_id='3'`, async(err,result)=>{
    if(err){
        res.json({status: false,msg:"There was an error while fetching data. Please Try again later"});
    }else{
        // console.log(result);
        if(result.length > 0){
            var resp = await bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].password);
            if(resp){
                const regtoken = jwt.sign({ id: result[0].user_id }, "943h9DH(H#R(*#HD(HD(RTH#(*Dh9th9gn498cNA(RN97BR()))))))d@ERR#R%", {
                        expiresIn: "90d",
                        // httpOnly: true
                    })
                    const cookiesOptions = {
                        expiresIn: new Date(Date.now() + "" * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
                        // httpOnly: true
                    }
                    res.cookie('checklogin', regtoken, cookiesOptions);

                res.json({status: true,msg:"Login successfully"});
            }else{
                res.json({status: false,msg:"Invalid login credentials"});
            }
        }else{
            res.json({status: false,msg:"Access Denied"});
        }
    }
})
})
```

code to hit the api:

```
const PostData = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formdata =  new FormData();
        formdata.append('email', user.email);
        formdata.append('password', user.password);

    var data = JSON.stringify({email:user.email, password:user.password})


        const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/user-login",data, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type" : "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            }
        })

    if(res.data.status){
        setCookie('testing', 'true')
        // localStorage.setItem("islogin","true");
        console.log("login done");
    }else{
        console.log("login failed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*The issue is that the cookie is being stored in the browser and not in the desktop application.*

The Node.js server, responsible for creating and transmitting the cookie to the client, has failed to store it in the Figma desktop application as it is an unconventional storage place for cookies - they are generally housed by web browsers, not desktop apps.

To retain data within a desktop app, you have multiple options to consider, such as utilizing a database, local storage, or even a user's system file, based on the specifications of your application.